# MongoDB : How to query or search case-insensitive values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

***What worked for me was :***

```
async function getByName(name) {
    try {
        const query = { username: { '$regex': `^${name}$`, '$options': 'i' }}
        const user = await collection.findOne(query);
        return user;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

You may replace the "findOne()" with a regular "find.

Write your thoughts.

Comment: What do you think is wrong in this way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.